# Remove views after animations are finished

Tags: java, android, animation

im looking for a way to remove Views from a layout with a scale animation. The method removeFromLayout should scale them to 0 and after every View is done with the animation, the layoud should be cleared.

```
public void removeFromLayout(){
        for(int i=all.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            all.get(i).animate()
                    .scaleX(0)
                    .scaleY(0)
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .setStartDelay(i*Activity.SIZE).start();
        }
        //After all animations are done, they should be removed
        layout.removeAllViews();
    }
```

So my question is, how can I "delay" layout.removeAllViews()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) class. You can set the animation listener. The following code snippet will give you an idea.

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, 
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.5f),
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.5f));
scaleDown.setDuration(1000);
scaleDown.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
               //Animation is complete, you can remove all your views here
               layout.removeAllViews();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
scaleDown.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CountDownTimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(200, 10) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
 {}

 public void onFinish() {
     layout.removeAllViews();
 }
 }.start();
```